# VSCode Auto Import picks external modules over internal

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

Some of our classes have a very common name, such as `Tag` and `User`. We rely on VSCode's Typescript Auto Import suggestions for fast development. However, we always have to replace certain imports where VSCode picks a class exported from `node_modules`, rather than a class that exists within our source folder.

Is there a preference we can set that helps VSCode disambiguate or favour internal symbols where present?

Comment: i also want this